# How to get the product availability information using Python Webscraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to write a simple code to fetch the product name, sku number, price and stock availability from an e-commerce website. The data is statically available in the HTML page of website in encoded JSON format. There are two different URLs from where I would need the above mentioned information to be scraped and then the data gets saved in different excel files. I am new to python and any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: first learn Python, next modules like `requests`/`urllib` to get HTML from server, and `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml` to parse HTML and search elements in data. OR you may try frameworks like `scrapy`. If page uses JavaScript then you can need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which can control real web browser. But Stackoverflow is not place to write tutorials. On Stackoverflow you should error message and code which gives this error and we try to resolve this small problem. Better use Google to find some tutorials or video tutorials on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code that can be used to fetch the statically encoded information from a webpage. In this case, the product information is part of the script tag as encoded json string. After this product information is dumped to csv files.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from datetime import date
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_products(url, filename, key):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    product_objects = None
    for script in soup.find_all('script'):
        if script.string is not None and key in script.string:
            content = str(script)
            begin = content.index("'[")
            end = content.index("]'")
            product_list = content[begin+1:end+1].decode('string_escape')
            product_objects = json.loads(product_list)

    fields = ['No.', 'Product', 'SKU','price', 'In-stock'] 
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:  
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)  
        csvwriter.writerow(fields)  

    idx = 1
    for object in product_objects:
        in_stock = "No"
        buyable = str(object["buyable"])
        if "true" in buyable:
            in_stock = "Yes"
        row = [str(idx), str(object["title"]), str(object["sku"]),
               str(object["default-price"]), in_stock]
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
        idx += 1

url = "https://www.dummy-ecommerce-test.com"

today_date = date.today().strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
filename = "./product-"+ today_date +".csv"
     
products = get_products(url, filename, 'test-key')
```